# How to make `find` return relative paths?

Tags: linux, find

I find this task:

> Find all files in the directory ​ `/srv/SAMPLE002`​ with a file
> extension of ​ `.tar` . Write a list of matching filenames, one
> per line, to the file
> `/opt/SAMPLE002/toBeCompressed.txt`​, which has
> already been created. Ensure that you specify a relative
> path to each file, using ​ `/srv/SAMPLE001`​ as the base
> directory for the relative path.

I created `SAMPLE001` and `SAMPLE002` directory in `srv`. In `SAMPLE002` I created 5 files with `.tar` extension. I have a problem with this part of the task:

> Ensure that you specify a relative
> path to each file, using ​ `/srv/SAMPLE001`​ as the base
> directory for the relative path.

I try like this:

```
 find /srv/SAMPLE001/../SAMPLE002  -type f -name "*.tar"
```

Is it a good solution for my task? I mean: *relative* path to each file. Maybe there's a better solution than mine.

Comment: The question would be better if you explicitly posted the result from the command you tried. It's not bad as it is, no need to improve after it was answered. In similar cases in the future consider posting the results of your tries along with the tries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The paths you get from your command are not relative.

The command does not explicitly specify an action for `find`, so implicit `-print` is used. `-print` prints pathnames. Pathnames are created [this way](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html#tag_20_47_03):

> […] Each path operand shall be evaluated unaltered as it was provided, including all trailing  characters; all pathnames for other files encountered in the hierarchy shall consist of the concatenation of the current path operand, a <slash> if the current path operand did not end in one, and the filename relative to the path operand. […]

This means if you specify `/srv/SAMPLE001/../SAMPLE002` as the only path operand (stating point) then you can only get lines from `-print` that start with this exact string.

Now check the definition of the [relative pathname](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_324):

> Relative Pathname
> A pathname not beginning with a <slash> character.

Anything you can get from your command must start with `/` (a <slash> character) because the path operand you used starts with `/`. Then by definitions these pathnames are not relative. The only way to get relative pathnames from `find … -print` is to provide a relative path operand (starting point).

In your case it can be like this:

```
cd /srv/SAMPLE001 && find ../SAMPLE002 -type f -name "*.tar"
```

(`&&` in case `cd` fails). Now every pathname must start with `../SAMPLE002`. The paths to the `.tar` files you're after will start with `../SAMPLE002/`. By definition they will be relative.

The definition is very terse. To know where the relativeness comes from, one needs to know [how *nix resolves paths](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html#tag_04_13). If you know this then you will agree that

```
/srv/SAMPLE001/../SAMPLE002/foo.rar
```

will point to the same `foo.rar`, no matter what the current working directory is. But

```
../SAMPLE002/foo.rar
```

will depend (rely) on the current working directory. The latter path *may or may not* point to the right `foo.rar`, depending on the current working directory. This is the point of being relative. If the current working directory is `/srv/SAMPLE001` then the path will point to the right file.

Note if `/srv/SAMPLE001/` didn't exist or if `/srv/SAMPLE001/..` didn't exist (e.g. `SAMPLE001` is a regular file), then `/srv/SAMPLE001/../SAMPLE002/foo.rar` could not be resolved. This is the only dependence from `/srv/SAMPLE001` in this case. The dependence does not make `/srv/SAMPLE001/../SAMPLE002/foo.rar` a relative path though.

---

Your original command does not write to `/opt/SAMPLE002/toBeCompressed.txt` at all. Use a [proper operator](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159513/108618) to redirect the output from `find`. E.g.:

```
cd /srv/SAMPLE001 && find ../SAMPLE002 -type f -name "*.tar" >/opt/SAMPLE002/toBeCompressed.txt
```

Comment: Hi thanks for answer :) Yes my code does not write to txt file, because i had problem with relative path :)

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below comamnd,

find /srv/SAMPLE002 -type f -name "*.tar" -fprintf  /opt/SAMPLE002/toBeCompressed.txt "%P \n"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).